# Extending the Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I'm implemented a `[CustomAuthorization]` attribute based on `[Authorize]` attribute. My attribute looks like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public eUserRole CustomRoles { get; set; } = eUserRole.Administrator; // If not specified, the required role is Administrator

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        AuthorizationSystem auth = new AuthorizationSystem(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal, this.CopyleaksRoles);
        var res = auth.Validate();
        if (!res)
            return false;

        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```

I splitted the logic (who to accept and who not) to seperated class. The method `AuthorizationSystem.Validate()` return true if the user is accepted according to his `CustomRoles` property.

My Controller looks like:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [CustomAuthorize(CustomRoles = eUserRole.Readonly)]
    public Response Do()
    {
        // ... Do something ...
    }
}
```

I'm running the application (C# + WebAPI) to check if it working.

I debugging the code and see that on the first run the minimum required role level is `Administrator` instead of `Readonly`. Because when using `[CustomAuthorize]` without any `CustomRoles`, it's define the **default** row to be `eUserRole.Administrator`. That mean that the first `CustomAuthorize` attribute that being called is the attribute on class level, **not on method level**.

How to make it call the attribute that on the method (`Do()`) before?

Comment: Seems a bit weird approach to have a controller with minimum access of Administrator, but a method of that controller with a minimum access of ReadOnly. There is self contradiction in your logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting confused by the fact that `AuthorizeAttribute` implements both `Attribute` and `IAuthorizationFilter`. What you need to do is make a globally registered `IAuthorizationFilter` and use it to determine whether the `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` exists on the action or controller. Then you can determine which takes precedence over the other.

### CustomAuthorizeAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public eUserRole CustomRoles { get; set; } = eUserRole.Administrator;
}
```

### CustomAuthoizationFilter

Here we save some steps by subclassing `AuthorizeAttribute`, but we don't intend for this to be an `Attribute` at all, only a globally registered filter.

Our filter contains Reflection code to determine which `CustomAuthorize` attribute takes precedence if both are defined. This is setup to make the action method override the controller, but you can make the logic more complex, if needed.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (base.IsAuthorized(actionContext))
        {
            var authorizeAttribute = GetAuthorizeAttribute(actionContext.ActionDescriptor);

            // Attribute doesn't exist - return true
            if (authorizeAttribute == null)
                return true;

            var roles = authorizeAttribute.CustomRoles;

            // Logic - return true if authorized, false if not authorized

        }

        return false;
    }

    private CustomAuthorizeAttribute GetAuthorizeAttribute(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        // Check action level
        CustomAuthorizeAttribute result = actionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes<CustomAuthorizeAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
            return result;

        // Check class level
        result = actionDescriptor
            .ControllerDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes<CustomAuthorizeAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return result;
    }
}
```

### Usage

We register the filter globally. For each request, `CustomAuthorizationFilter` scans the action and controller in the request to see if the attribute exists. If so, it then runs the logic.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Register our Custom Authorization Filter
        config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizationFilter());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** Technically you can keep them both in the same class, but it is less confusing if you separate them into the components that that *actually are* rather than making a single class that does more than one job (attribute and filter).

Reference: [Passive Attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/)

Comment: When attempting to implement this I get "There is no suitable method for override" on IsAuthorized

Comment: That is because this queation is about MVC 5.